# ng-pattern dynamic object property

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in an input and it works fine

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/">
```

I also get the same pattern via a JSON object under validation.decfield but if I do this.

```
ng-pattern="validation.decField">
```

It doesn't work... I've seen other examples of folks doing this... Why doesn't it work? I am using angular 1.3.

The data type of validation.decField coming from json is String. I tried several ways to convert it so that it could be understood by Angular. No error, it just doens't limit the field like the plain pattern in the field does.

Comment: Doesn't work mean? any error? What is the data type of `validation.decField`?

Comment: The regex should not be in quotes in in the controller.  Can you show how you are defining `validation.decField`?

Comment: the value is in JSON... It comes back as jsonPattern : "/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/"

Comment: @chrislhardin I've updated my answer to show creating a `RegExp` object from an existing regex string.  Taking the string value from your JSON response and using the `RegExp` constructor should work.

Comment: My whole problem was that my string was coming from a prop file and I didn't escape the \ characters so it was munging my result. Your example was flawless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure to use JavaScript regex as the type (instead of a quoted pattern) in the controller all should be fine.

If your are receiving the regex as a string (in JSON), you should construct a new `RegExp` object:

```
validation.decField = new RegEx('/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/', 'i');
```

Below is snippet showing everything working (using Angular 1.2.23).

Notice in the example that the `decField` is set to `/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/`, not `'/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/'`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.validation = {
    
        decField: new RegExp('/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?$/', 'i')
    };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

      <form name="frm">
        
        <label>Decimal:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="validation.decField"/>
        
      </form>
      
      {{ frm.$valid }}
  
    </div>
</div>
```